# Netty handler for capturing/logging all traffic

Tags: java, netty

I would like to capture for logging purposes all traffic that is passing through my Netty server. Is there a simple solution at the level of Netty (not OS)?

I have a good idea of what writing such a handler entails, but first I wanted to ask if something is already available. If not, then I'll implement it and post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `LoggingHandler` using like this? or write custom handler imitate the handler:

```
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
  .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
  .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
  .childHandler(httpServerInitializer);
```